# Minimizing a coefficient to still get an answer from Solve

Tags: equation-solving, functions, calculus-and-analysis, numerics

```
i[t_, res_] := ((-8.22026327513615`*^-9 + 250.` capacitance) E^(-(t/(
capacitance res))))/(capacitance res);

capacitance = 1.08267*c;
NSolve[i[250*10^-6, res] == 10^-6, res, Reals]
```

For the above code, how can I find which value on the coefficient, in front of **c** (row 4), which is the smallest number that still yields a solution for **NSolve** below.

I'm solving for **res** but it is only possible to find **res** if it is greater or equal to 1.08267~~. Mind you, I tried this far by hand. Is there any way of finding the value automatically?

To clarify; by substituting the coefficient 1.08267 into 1.08, there is no solution to the NSolve below. **Can I find the minimum coefficient somehow?**

Edit 1:

```
i[t_, res_] := ((-8.22026327513615`*^-9 + 250.` capacitance) E^(-(t/(
capacitance res))))/(capacitance res);

capacitance = k*Subscript[c, 0];
Solve[i[250*10^-6, res] == 10^-6, {res, k}, Reals]
```

Comment: Did you try arbitrary precision numbers? Alternatively, if you replace those numbers with parameters `Solve` (instead of `NSolve`) can give you exact solutions.

Comment: I did not try arbitrary precision numbers; unfortunately I don't even know what they are. And I tried the code I added in my edit, but it gave no good results.

Comment: Try replacing **all** numbers by named parameters. Arbitrary precision: see [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionNumbers.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve for the reciprocal of `res`:

```
capacitance =.;
Solve[i[250*10^-6, res] == 10^-6 /. res -> 1/reciprocal, reciprocal, Reals]
```

> Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result. >>

```
{{reciprocal -> 
   ConditionalExpression[-4000. capacitance ProductLog[-(383412659/(
       4000 (-3151753 + 95853164750000000 capacitance)))], 
    0 < capacitance < 3.28811*10^-11 || capacitance >= 3.55993*10^-11 || capacitance < 0]},
 {reciprocal -> 
   ConditionalExpression[-4000. capacitance ProductLog[-1, -(
       383412659/(4000 (-3151753 + 95853164750000000 capacitance)))], 
    capacitance >= 3.55993*10^-11]}}
```

The question of minimizing the coefficient in front of `c` does not make sense to me.  If we call the coefficient `a`, then we have

```
capacitance = a c
```

No matter how small we make `a`, we can always adjust `c` so that `capacitance` is in the ranges shown in the conditional expressions above.